Allow all characters, Numbers and Special Characters in regex for Config file
I am unfamiliar with regex, I am trying to allow all characters in my URL. I am working with 2 config files.  RewriteMaps.config and RewriteRules.config. Any help would be appreciated.
The URL has tracking code (I've masked the actual URL): https://www.HS.org/HF/community/giving/donate?utm_source=mail&utm_medium=url-in-print&utm_id=il-hfg-fd-grateful-pt
RewriteMaps.config:
<rewriteMap name="HF-Redirects">
<add key="grateful" value="community/giving/donate?utm_source=mail&utm_medium=url-in-print&utm_id=il-hfg-fd-grateful-pt" />
</rewriteMap>
RewriteRules.config - I have tried to change the "match url" and "pattern" lines:
<rule name="HF-Redirects" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.+?)\/?$" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www\.)?HF.org$" />
<add input="{HF-Redirects:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.HF.org/HF/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
I've tried adding "\W" and changing <match url="^(.+?)\/?$" /> to <match url="^(.+?)\/?\W$" />
I've tried changing <match url="^(.+?)\/?$" /> to <match url=".*" />
and /[\w\W]*/
